# Vector Field on the Real Projective Plane F-related to Vector Field on Plane

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to understand the problem from this post [Finding a $F$-related field in $\mathbb{RP}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544726/finding-a-f-related-field-in-mathbbrp2)

The problem is I am getting something different for the line $Y_{p} = \cdots$ in the answer given by ulilaka.

Here is what I have:

$$
J(\phi_{2} \circ \phi_{3}^{-1}) =  \begin{pmatrix}
    1/y & -x/y^{2} \\
    0 & -1/y^{2}
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
J(\phi_{2} \circ \phi_{3}^{-1}) \begin{pmatrix}
    \partial_{u} \\
    \partial_{v}
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    \partial_{x} \\
    \partial_{y}
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\implies \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial u} - \frac{x}{y^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial v}, \hspace{2mm} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \frac{-1}{y^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial v}
$$

Then

$$
x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{-\partial}{\partial u} + \left(\frac{x}{y} - \frac{x}{y^{2}}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial v} = \frac{-\partial}{\partial u} + (u - uv)\frac{\partial}{\partial v}
$$

Something tells me there is something wrong with this Jacobian. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action of the Jacobian is not the same as above, I believe that the matrix takes the basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right\}$ (induced by $\varphi_3$) to the basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right\}$ (induced by $\varphi_2$).

$Y_p$'s coordinates with respect to the $\varphi_3$-induced basis are $\begin{pmatrix} -y \\ x \end{pmatrix}$ and we see,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{y} & -\frac{x}{y^2}\\
0 & -\frac{1}{y^2}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -y \\ x \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 - \frac{x^2}{y^2} \\ -\frac{x}{y^2}  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 - u^2 \\ -uv \end{pmatrix}
$$
are precisely the coordinates found by ulilaka in their answer.